# simple php for each it is not adding sums well

Tags: php, laravel

there is 3 positions in `$input['order_items']`, i am extracting `$orderItem['subtotal']` which gives to me the total of a product and `$orderItem['subtotal_tax']` which gives to me total tax of such product, what i am doing is adding `subtotal` with `subtotal_tax` , the problem is the function is not summing or adding correctly the value, for example in first position i got this:

```
"total": "13302",
      "total_tax": "0",
```

second position i got this:

```
"total": "9711",
      "total_tax": "0",
```

third position i got this:

```
"subtotal": "14022",
      "subtotal_tax": "0",
```

as result of the sum it should give to me this:

```
37035
```

but i am getting:

```
28044
```

must ask, why? and how to correct it? thanks in foward

```
$i = 0;
$nvCantVar = 0;
$subtotal = 0;
$subtotal_tax = 0;
$NotaVentaDetalleDTO = '';
foreach ($input['order_items'] as $orderItem) {
    $i++;

    $subtotal = $orderItem['subtotal'];
    $subtotal_tax = $orderItem['subtotal_tax'];
    $nvCantVar =  $subtotal + $subtotal_tax;  
}

$nvCantVar = $nvCantVar + $nvCantVar;
```

why could this be happening?

Comment: The reason why you're getting 28044 is `$nvCantVar = $nvCantVar + $nvCantVar;`. The last value of `$nvCantVar` is **14022**, then  $nvCantVar = 14022 + 14022 which is 28044. Note that inside foreach, you are using `$nvCantVar =` instead of `$nvCantVar +=` so it will overwrite the value instead of accumulating the total value. You should also remove the statement after foreach, which is redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a scalar variable in the loop and therefore over writing the accumulator with the last value each time rather than accumulating a grand total.

Instead of `=` use `+=` to add each value to the existing value of the accumulator in the loop

```
$nvCantVar = 0;

foreach ($input['order_items'] as $orderItem) {
    $nvCantVar +=  $orderItem['subtotal'] + $orderItem['subtotal_tax'];  
}

echo $nvCantVar;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP code isn't following the logic you want at all.

Firstly why the `$i` what is this being used for? Secondly your code is looping, overriding the value of `$nvCantVar` and then simply adding the final value of this variable to itself to get the new value.

So the math it is doing is:

```
$nvCantVar = 14022 + 14022
```

What you want is something like

```
$nvCantTotal = 0;
foreach ($input['order_items'] as $orderItem) {
  $subtotal = $orderItem['subtotal'];
  $subtotal_tax = $orderItem['subtotal_tax'];
  $nvCantTotal += $subtotal + $subtotal_tax;  
}
```